# Jquery live('change', function() wont trigger drop down

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, cascadingdropdown

Anyone can see anything wrong with this code? It is connected to a php function that echos Json data. I am running Jquery 1.9.1. I belive the problem is at the end of the Jquery script, but I can´t find any solution...

```
var formObject = {
   run : function(obj) {
        if (obj.val() === '') {
       obj.nextAll('.update').html('<option value="">----</option>').attr('disabled', true);
   } else {
       var id = obj.attr('id');
       var v = obj.val();
       jQuery.getJSON('func/blankett_func.php', { id : id, value : v }, function(data) {
            if (!data.error) {
                obj.next('.update').html(data.list).removeAttr('disabled');
            } else {
                obj.nextAll('.update').html('<option value="">----</option>').attr('disabled', true);
            }
        });
    }
}
  };
$(function() {

    $('.update').live('change', function() {
        formObject.run($(this));
    });

});
```

The Php function:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$value = $_GET['value'];

try {

    $objDb = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=blankett', 'root', 'root');
    $objDb->exec('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');

    $sql = "SELECT * 
            FROM `region`
            WHERE `master_id` = ?";
    $statement = $objDb->prepare($sql);
    $statement->execute(array($value));
    $list = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if (!empty($list)) {

        $out = array('<option value="">Select one</option>');

        foreach($list as $row) {
            $out[] = '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['region'].'</option>';
        }

        echo json_encode(array('error' => false, 'list' => implode('', $out)));

    } else {
        echo json_encode(array('error' => true));
    }

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo json_encode(array('error' => true));
}

    } else {
echo json_encode(array('error' => true));
  }
```

Comment: quite shore the problem is in the javascript?

Comment: Try with just the javascript, without any dynamic code

Comment: why do users of php language misrecognize the existance of MVC?

Comment: thiagoh would you like to share a link to somewhere I can reed up on MVC? Is there any good resource?

Comment: Have you checked console for errors? I believe `live()` is obsolete in 1.9.1, perhaps even removed. Should be `$(document).on('change', '.update', function() {`.

Comment: live() was removed in jQuery 1.9. Use on()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the original code was in the .live of the javascript, it should be changed to .on

The reason for it not triggering was that jQuery changed the API.
http://api.jquery.com/on/

The new jQuery script:

```
var formObject = {
run : function(obj) {
    if (obj.val() === '') {
        obj.nextAll('.update').html('<option value="">----</option>').attr('disabled', true);
    } else {
        var id = obj.attr('id');
        var v = obj.val();
        jQuery.getJSON('func/blankett_func.php', { id : id, value : v }, function(data) {
            if (!data.error) {
                obj.next('.update').html(data.list).removeAttr('disabled');
            } else {
                obj.nextAll('.update').html('<option value="">----</option>').attr('disabled', true);
            }
        });
    }
}
};
$(function() {

$('.update').on('change', function() {
    formObject.run($(this));
});

});
```

Comment: yes @cspray was right the problem was that .live was removed and what should be used is .on

Comment: Someone can close this post btw.